# Tfs_Warehouse corruted data in Dim.Person and Dim.Date

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-reports, tfs-analysis

We are trying to alicve our `Reporting and Analysis Services` in `Team foundation Server` (currently it is14.0.23128.0 (Tfs2015)).

It was not using for a couple years.

And now we want to use it. But when we connected to our analysis via `Excel` we've faced to strange data in report builder:

All Date boxes are empty and lots of SID Instead of people:
[image: Dim.Person]
[image: Dim.Date]

After that we went to our `SQL Server` where all `TFS` databases are and looked at tables:

This is Dim.Date table in Tfs_Warehouse

And this is Dim.Person table. It is filled with SID's and normal names. Some of SID's in AD have normal names. But here are they presented by SID.

So that is the problem we have.

We tried to solve it by ourself.

So what we have tried to do:

First of all we tried just to rebuild `Reporting Services`. It did not worked.

Also we tried to rebuild services with deleting Tfs_Warehouse and Tfs_Analysis databases. It did not worked too.

After that i installed an extra TFS on another pc. And its database is filled with correct data.

After that I turned off reporting service, deleted Tfs_Warehouse and Tfs_Analysis databases, deleted `SQL Server Analysis and Reporting` features, reboot a vm and installed them again. Configured Analysis and Reporting features and turned `TFS` Reporting service on. When all tables were filled i have seen that corrupted data. Just same as i saw at first.

And after that i did all that i wrote in a previous try but also i reinstall an application server. Result is the same. Data is corrupted.

Also i tried to switch app server from "good" `TFS`. But did not helped.

Have anyone any ideas about that? :)

Comment: 1). Was the TFS server moved from one machine to another before? 2). From which version was TFS2015 upgraded from? 3). I see that null data rows in [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[DimDate] table are years ago. Are latest data entries still get null values?

Comment: @Vicky-MSFT Tfs was not ever moved from one machine to another. But it uses cluster of two database machines. but i think it is not important. All dates in [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[DimDate] are null. Even after rebuild